# Dumping a subclass of gtk.ListStore using pickle

Tags: python, gtk, pickle, getstate

I am trying to dump a custom class using pickle.  The class was subclassed from gtk.ListStore, since that made it easier to store particular data and then display it using gtk.  This can be reproduced as shown here.

```
import gtk
import pickle
import os

class foo(gtk.ListStore):
    pass

if __name__=='__main__':
    x = foo(str)
    with open(os.path.expandvars('%userprofile%\\temp.txt'),'w') as f:
        pickle.dump(x,f)
```

The solution that I have tried was to add a `__getstate__` function into my class.  As far as I understand the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__), this should take precedence for pickle so that it no longer tries to serialize the ListStore, which it is unable to do.  However, I still get an identical error from pickle.dump when I try to pickle my object.  The error can be reproduced as follows.

```
import gtk
import pickle
import os

class foo(gtk.ListStore):
    def __getstate__(self):
        return 'bar'

if __name__=='__main__':
    x = foo(str)
    with open(os.path.expandvars('%userprofile%\\temp.txt'),'w') as f:
        pickle.dump(x,f)
```

In each case, pickle.dump raises a TypeError, "can't pickle ListStore objects".  Using print statements, I have verified that the `__getstate__` function is run when using pickle.dump.  I don't see any hints as to what to do next from the documentation, and so I'm in a bit of a bind.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

With this method you can even use json instead of pickle for your purpose.

Here is a quick working example to show you the steps you need to employ to pickle "unpicklable types" like `gtk.ListStore`. Essentially you need to do a few things:

1. Define `__reduce__` which returns a function and arguments needed to reconstruct the instance.
2. Determine the column types for your ListStore. The method `self.get_column_type(0)` returns a Gtype, so you will need to map this back to the corresponding Python type. I've left that as an exercise - in my example I've employed a hack to get the column types from the first row of values.
3. Your `_new_foo` function will need to rebuild the instance.

Example:

```
import gtk, os, pickle

def _new_foo(cls, coltypes, rows):
    inst = cls.__new__(cls)
    inst.__init__(*coltypes)
    for row in rows:
        inst.append(row)
    return inst

class foo(gtk.ListStore):

    def __reduce__(self):
        rows = [list(row) for row in self]
        # hack - to be correct you'll really need to use 
        # `self.get_column_type` and map it back to Python's 
        # corresponding type.
        coltypes = [type(c) for c in rows[0]]
        return _new_foo, (self.__class__, coltypes, rows)

x = foo(str, int)
x.append(['foo', 1])
x.append(['bar', 2])

s = pickle.dumps(x)

y = pickle.loads(s)
print list(y[0])
print list(y[1])
```

Output:

```
['foo', 1]
['bar', 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you subclass object, `object.__reduce__` takes care of calling `__getstate__`. It would seem that since this is a subclass of `gtk.ListStore`, the default implementation of `__reduce__` tries to pickle the data for reconstructing a `gtk.ListStore` object first, then calls your `__getstate__`, but since the `gtk.ListStore` can't be pickled, it refuses to pickle your class. The problem should go away if you try to implement `__reduce__` and `__reduce_ex__` instead of `__getstate__`.

```
>>> class Foo(gtk.ListStore):
...     def __init__(self, *args):
...             super(Foo, self).__init__(*args)
...             self._args = args
...     def __reduce_ex__(self, proto=None):
...             return type(self), self._args, self.__getstate__()
...     def __getstate__(self):
...             return 'foo'
...     def __setstate__(self, state):
...             print state
... 
>>> x = Foo(str)
>>> pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(x))
foo
<Foo object at 0x18be1e0 (__main__+Foo-v3 at 0x194bd90)>
```

As an addition, you may try to consider other serializers, such as `json`. There you take full control of the serialiazaton process by defining how custom classes are to be serialized yourself. Plus by default they come without the security issues of `pickle`.